# Blender fluid sim only shows particles and cannot show the fluid as a solid or a mesh

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am new-ish to blender and have just started using the fluid options. I can get to the point where I have all my settings for the inflow and I have everything ready to go, but when I bake it, the preview (even render preview) just shows small blue particles instead of a liquid mesh. I was able to get the mesh yesterday, so maybe i hit something wrong? Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you have a "Mesh" panel enabled in Physics Properties? Are you able to get fluid mesh if you start from scratch with default cube? If you want to solve issue with a specific file you would have to let as see. Attach your simplified blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to scroll down in **fluid domain settings** and **check the mesh option**. If you have the fluid baked, there should be an option **Bake Mesh**. This will bake the mesh around the fluid particles and then you should be able to shade it from there. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: The _Bake Mesh_ option is only there if he set the _Cache Type_ to _Modular_, Then there's a _Bake Data_ button as well. If you set the _Cache Type_ to _All_ (or _Final_ in earlier versions), there's a _Bake All_ button and you don't have to bake data and mesh separately. Since it's unclear from the question if he even checked _Mesh_ in his domain, it's not easy to say if he needs to bake a mesh separately or not.